# How to use the same parameters with two overloaded functions in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, overloading

I tried to call another overloaded function within an overloaded function in typescript. Since the type `Func2` is identical to the type `Func1`, it is certain that the arguements passed onto `func1` from `func2` will be typed correctly. However, typescript seems to be unable to pick that up, and throwing an error.

```
type Func1 = {
  (a: string, b: string): void
  (a: undefined, b: undefined): void
}
const func1: Func1 = (a, b) => {
  console.log(a, b)
}

type Func2 = {
  (a: string, b: string): void
  (a: undefined, b: undefined): void
}
const func2: Func2 = (a, b) => {
  func1(a, b)
  console.log(a, b)
}

/*
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(a: string, b: string): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(a: undefined, b: undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
*/
```

How can I resolve this?

**EDIT:** Here's the actual implementation that I was attempting:

```
type ParseRandomArgs = {
  (a: undefined, b: undefined): [number, number]
  (a: number, b: undefined): [number, number]
  (a: number, b: number): [number, number]
  (a: [number, number], b: undefined): [number, number]
  (a: [number], b: undefined): [number, number]
}

type RandomNumber = {
  (a: undefined, b: undefined): number
  (a: number, b: undefined): number
  (a: number, b: number): number
  (a: [number, number], b: undefined): number
  (a: [number], b: undefined): number
}

const isNullish = (value: any) => value === undefined || value === null

const parseRandomArgs: ParseRandomArgs = (a, b) => {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    if (a.length === 2) return a
    return [0, a[0]]
  }
  else if (isNullish(b)) return [0, isNullish(a) ? 1 : a as number]
  else return [a as number, b as number]
}

const randomFloat: RandomNumber = (a, b) => {
  let [min, max] = parseRandomArgs(a, b) // [min, max]
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}

const randomInt: RandomNumber = (a, b) => {
  let [min, max] = parseRandomArgs(a, b) // [min, max]
  min = Math.ceil(min)
  max = Math.floor(max)
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}
```

Comment: Can you describe how you intend to use these type definitions?

Comment: @kingkupps This is just an example for demo. What I was trying to make is a simple util random number generator with convenient overloads (`a` and `b` can be numbers, `a` can be a number array, etc.). After calling the randomizer function, the args will be passed to another function to be parsed. The two functions have the same overloaded types.

Comment: Do you mind including your random number generator function (and how it is meant to be used) as an example in your question? The intended use might help others provide a more relevant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mike mentioned, making `undefined` arguments optional makes overloading simpler to work out. This should work:

```
type RandomGenerator = {
    (start: number, end?: number): number
    (range: [number, number]): number;
    (range: [number]): number;
}

const randomFloat: RandomGenerator = (start, end?) => {
    const [min, max] = parseRandomArgs(start, end as number | undefined);
    return computeRandom(min, max);
}

const randomInt: RandomGenerator = (start, end?) => {
    const [min, max] = parseRandomArgs(start, end as number | undefined);
    return Math.floor(computeRandom(min, max));
}

const computeRandom = (min: number, max: number): number => {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

const parseRandomArgs = (first: number | [number, number] | [number], second: number | undefined): [number, number] => {
    let args: [number, number];
    if (Array.isArray(first) && first.length === 1) {
        args = [0, first[0]];
    } else if (Array.isArray(first) && first.length === 2) {
        args = first;
    } else {
        args = Number.isFinite(second) ? [first, second as number] : [0, first];
    }
    const [min, max] = args;
    return [Math.ceil(min), Math.floor(max)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to duplicate your parameters or even use any assertions: you can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to let the compiler discriminate nullish types.

And by using labelled tuples for the parameters, you can even get a nicer developer experience via helpful IntelliSense suggestions in your editor:

[image]

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgLACgpQAoEMBOWC2AzlBAB7ARwAmxArnANZwD2A7nANoC6UAvFFjghuAGlToAShEK0ANsD4ChYlAD5FACgB0O3AHNCALky4ChAJR91UmfIDcqVKEhQAws3z5mcbHiKKOcSgOfCxSAH5jOFp8ACMIHC4VdBCASzgomPicEShQiMy4hKSgtLgAQWoAWTDjMsLs3PyG4pK0YPyAeThZEDrmqGiixLauBxQncGhfQgh4RXgEd09vXzMOIeyk4M2E3N3E1XHnaAlBKg95-kXlrx9TIg2s4v3nnCPHFAAzegBjYFS3igqUIADk5LIQQALKAIAAqqg0ADcsLJaBBjHDzMYUWjoCCoABRUi-NFUCDw3Kg7zg2SyLCxWQUhHqADeQRwEGAtBwcCguPRfF4-Ho5K+6QgVCgAB9pfzUYLhfxonTxgBfT6-byEBRgXCzM7UDzlHAGYwzOZ8-jaXSmixWKDs9pauA64JYXKxHj8fSEcboVJfKAaE14EBaEGhrAgDRYcyWTnc3kCLRMuB6YAwpVQABMUHCAigdQADLksBxi1wxkFA8GQbTIYQobH41BEzy+RXcgBGavtdvJ+sQ6EaWKWAtdgQ8OoeqBe9XjVAut14I34GCyZhYYDGQ0XddW4M6LS+yy8NlBZcKMpNMLeqB6nAG87Gu02k928z+ttcjtQGqZloq77holgAFTBvkUAALR5OklgANRwXAC6atqCjAR4ACScA7lAe6XIe76ng6TroEy174Okt6kPej7PmuJoGMRn7flRh4AVCWi-BAqSyBo7FfkEUH8JxWhfJuzA4AJYRCf2v7JmJEnMFJGhiZh+CgVAEEyaQMHIYhBmoSgQA)

```ts
type Fn<
  Params extends unknown[] = any[],
  Result = any,
> = (...args: Params) => Result;

type CommonParams = [
  [max?: number],
  [min: number, max?: number],
  [minAndMax: [min: number, max: number]],
  [maxOnly: [max: number]],
];

type ParseFn = Fn<CommonParams[number], [number, number]>;
type RandomFn = Fn<CommonParams[number], number>;

function isNullish <T>(value: T): value is Exclude<T, NonNullable<T>> {
  return value === undefined || value === null;
}

const parseRandomArgs: ParseFn = (...args) => {
  const [a, b] = args;
  if (Array.isArray(a)) return a.length === 2 ? a : [0, a[0]];
  if (isNullish(a)) return [0, 1];
  return isNullish(b) ? [0, a] : [a, b];
};

const randomFloat: RandomFn = (...args) => {
  const [min, max] = parseRandomArgs(...args);
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

const randomInt: RandomFn = (...args) => {
  let [min, max] = parseRandomArgs(...args);
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you try make too clean code

Considering the second example (with a random number): typescript actually join all possible variants of arguments

```
const randomInt: RandomNumber = (a, b) => {
   //a: number | [number, number] | [number] | undefined
   //b: number | undefined
}
```

and your RandomNumber/ParseRandomArgs definitions can be used only for call validation

so the first solution is to extend ParseRandomArgs with the union of all args

```
type ParseRandomArgs = {
 ...
 (a: [number]| [number, number] | number | undefined, b: number | undefined): [number, number]
}
```

second, move such union to protected function and convert ParseRandomArgs to a proxy

```
const _parseRandomArgs = function(a: [number] | [number,number] | number | undefined ,b?: number | undefined): [number,number]{
   ...
}

const parseRandomArgs: ParseRandomArgs = (a, b) => {
  return _parseRandomArgs(a,b);
}

const randomFloat: RandomNumber = (a, b) => {
  let [min, max] = _parseRandomArgs(a, b) // [min, max]
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

and I suggest you make all undefined arguments - optional

full code in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgQwE4GcoCUEDsAmB7AWwEEkBzFGAXhgG9gYYAKBAfgC4YBXXKAMwEssUHABoYAI3ZceAoTgCUHANpZOBcVCRjV6zQF16TBBx0atEqdxx9BwxTBVqz2p-sPMTr8+M+6k9xz8XPwMGDwdTTWCzPTFJDisbOQDI81TQo2V0uISZWwUsr2i3BgB6UpAAC34KGul+PCwYPF4YBAAbdrayFHpyzIivPQAfQaCYdJhR1Knpa1lhHImvWcSFgrHnZZDgAF9gUEhYTFxCADkV6jow1lz5-LjLPOTfM3djba34uaS7V813v9vED7KlAZsop99I87r8NmCboUQjCfutQV49gcAMaNFAgGA1C6dGqVKhMABuHU4UA42DA8ioAD4YJT2tSqJRqGt8lNRqz2ZzqKpOtjcfiAPoQZBoE74Yg9Mm8bhYkANLDhQIxWaaqKTaYrUbcuQwETfGaG55-CFadLXBgE1qMEhIBBgAB0NWdruY8gZdvt9v4joQbvaUCwpCqHOoACYGUgoCBOEgmghDAGGAmkymHAAGMQIJS5vQZBj7ANQdpoB1MQmcYkoSqMcS+mBZ5NNItiOsNpsIBksGAARhgtLaFHS6Zgler7ZzSgQ46h3iXk-2wBxWDxMClqAw2DlJHIHEQe9lhCPFGozDiDMozLtc6akul+9O8vIN5bAG5MaKt-iLrvgAYu0eAICAHDngQFx+GSN4SHeD6GGG+JKAQghiAQCAAB56GSL5ngeF49AhLYwP06GYTA2F4YYT4wAAshBlRukBcqMAyABUTC0TAAC0NGCAyADUQlYH+m7buxhAAJJYJBMDQbBZjwQgt5MrQKGJg4GFYFhuH4dQhEysRH4oGRDKUXpBl0QwelksxVRuliUD8O0jB6fIhh8dQTmsbwYF4Egnm4d5maJh2TEsW6gV4MFjD+WxZmcTAPGhThAniaJ2V-jJBDySAnG-vlhWMEO8glWZZVDiIcZVe+NV1ZVFGlKy-A4BBaowLwCDuUAA)